# Using package while running; Error "Could not find or load main class"

Tags: java, class

```
classpath=  C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\jre\lib\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin;
path=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_111\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_111\bin;
```

```
package seleniumTest;
public class SampleTest {

public static void main(String[] args) 

{
  System.out.println("hello");        
}    

}
```

My question is I am not able run the Java file while using the package. 
I am new to Java so not able to find the root cause. Please help me out. 
Its not able to reach the main class.

Comment: Please show the command line you use to run the class and/or explain what you mean by "while using the package".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18093928/what-does-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-mean